# Changing the menu on a wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using the 2011 theme on wordpress  and I would like to make the font that appears on the primary menu bigger and more stylish, is it possible for me to achieve this and if so, how to I go about it. [sosytee.wordpress.com](http://sosytee.wordpress.com) is the site i am working on and i would like to change the menu to a font similar to the orange letters in my banner as well as the size also

Comment: Quick ans: *Modify CSS!* Because without any details provided here we can't help you much.

Comment: @Log1c have edited to include a link to my website, am not sure if you can shed more light now.

Comment: Follow answer provided by abhi vinay

Answer (score 2):

You can edit style.css file for this.

Please add child theme and edit the CSS file

Main menu:

```
#access ul { 
   font-size:20px; /* change it as per your need*/
}
```

Dropdown:

```
#access ul ul a { ... }
```

Firebug plugin for Firefox may help to inspect CSS style.

Comment: Given you are hosted on WordPress.com, you will probably need the Custom Upgrade package to edit CSS. http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: plugin is for your firefox browser .it has to be installed on your localmachine . if you open your wordpress site in firefox ( or any website) you can inspect style sheet elements with this firebug add -on . Please  go here and install it https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ . Actually This  tool is not mandatory for you . To edit font for wordpress menu, edit style.css file from your worpress installation location or Administration menu as i said earlier . As Lefters said, if your website is hosted on wordpress.com you need custom upgrade package .